# twice call in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I do request like this:

```
submitForm(data : any){
    if(Utils.regEmail(data.email) && data.username && data.username.length <= 10) {
      var me = this;
      if (data.current && data.current.length >= 8) {
        if ((!data.pass && !data.confirm )|| (data.pass && data.confirm && data.pass=== data.confirm && data.pass.length >= 8)) {
          this.indexService.makeFileRequest('http://localhost:server/updateUser', this.form.value, this.files).subscribe((data) => {})...
```

The makeFileRequest function looks like:

```
makeFileRequest (url: string, params: any,  files: File[]): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      let formData: FormData = new FormData(),xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      if (files) {
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          formData.append("file", files[i], files[i].name);
        }
      }
      formData.append("username", params.username);
     ..... append many fields

      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
            observer.complete();
          } else {
            observer.error(xhr.response);
          }
        }
      };

      xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
        this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);

        this.progressObserver.next(this.progress);
      };

      xhr.open('POST', url, true);
      xhr.send(formData);
    });
  }
```

And in the http://localhost:server/updateUser I do request to API to save my data. But I noticed that when I submit form two request go to server. Why does it happen? What I do wrong here?

Comment: The first request could be the OPTIONS request and the second could be the POST. Have you checked to make sure that is not the case, or is it two POST requests?

Comment: The first request is this one makeFileRequest, which do ajax post request to  http://localhost:server/updateUser 
And the second request do request like this:
app.post("/updateUser", function(req, res) {
  var body = req.body.body;
  api.request({
    url:`api/saveUser`,
    method : 'PUT',
   ...